# NGINX rewrite 2 adresses to same destination

Tags: nginx

I am looking to rewrite 2 different addresses to the same destination address. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
location = /foo/bar/, /to/fu/ {
  return 301 /re/bar/;
}
```

Or do I have to create two seperate redirects?

```
location = /foo/bar/ {
  return 301 /re/bar/;
}
```

--

```
location = /to/fu/ {
  return 301 /re/bar/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this by using a regexp instead of a path in location, I don't recommend it. You'll end up with a config file that is complex, making it very hard to maintain.

I would probably remove the location entries and instead use multiple rewrites, since that'd give me a better overview, like this:

```
server_name_in_redirect on;
rewrite /foo/bar/ /re/bar/ permanent;
rewrite /to/fu/   /re/bar/ permanent;
```

In my opinion, this makes it easy to see what redirects you're using and how to add more of them. But this is very much a personal preference, and using locations isn't wrong!

Comment: Uhm... `location` blocks can take a regex, if you use `~` instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to define `/foo/bar/` and `/foo/bar` as the same thing? Or do 2 separate rewrites need to be created again?

Comment: As womble said, you can do this with a regexp. As I wrote, I prefer to use a list of rewrites as it makes it easier to maintain the config file.

Answer (score 0):

[The Fine Manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) indicates that comma-separating multiple URIs is not permitted, and you'll either have to use two separate blocks, or do a regex match.